# Loop using variable - r.mapcalc GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, ndvi, bash

I am doing threshold classification of NDVI rasters. One equation looks like that:

```
r.mapcalc 'prog_r43_n65=if(ndvi_r43_n65>=0.6,1,2)'
```

Now I want to make a loop for more than 2000 rasters, so I created this:

```
for red in {43..64}
do
for nir in {65..193}
do
progi="ndvi_r"$red"_n"$nir    #I have files named ex. ndvi_r43_n65
progowa="prog_r"$red"_n"$nir
r.mapcalc '"$progowa"=if("$progi">=0.6,1,2)'
done
done
```

And here is the problem.. It does not read "progi" as a variable.. Does somebody guess why?

Comment: How do you invoke the bash script?  What system are you using?   Try an `echo ...` in the script with the same argument as `r.mapcalc` or the an `echo $progi $progwa` and see if the variables are being assigned as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I made it finally.. One simple thing: ' despite " :

```
for red in {43..64}
do
for nir in {65..193}
do
r.mapcalc 'prog_r'$red'_nir'$nir'=if(ndvi_r'$red'_n'$nir'>=0.6,1,2)'
done
done
```

Comment: Getting the quoteing right is sometimes hard.

Answer (score 0):

It is the single quotes around the argument to r.mapcalc, they inhibit the shell expansion of the $ variables.  maybe try this:

```
r.mapcalc "'$progowa=if($progi>=0.6,1,2)'"
```

It should expand the shell variables and pass the single quotes to r.mapcalc.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Bummer.  Seemed to work on my command line, but within scripts, there can be another level of parsing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
r.mapcalc "$progowa = if(${progi}>=0.6,1,2)"
```

i.e. space around the '=' and enclose the variable in in {}

Comment: This one as well, does not work.

Comment: This might not work because the bash interpreter uses up the quotes and passes this as three arguments to mapcalc.r, and then redirects the output to some awkward file name.