# Looping with a variable r.mapcalc GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, masking, r.mapcalc

I want to crop a raster based on another one, inside a loop. I created a mask (`MASK`) and then cropped the old raster (`old`), creating a new raster (`new`).

```
r.mask vector=EU@PERMANENT #my mask 
r.mapcalc "new = old"
```

For a single raster, it works. However, I have many old rasters, and I want to create a loop. I tried this:

```
for i in `cat /myPath/myRasters.txt | tr -d '\r'`
do
echo SET REGION 
g.region vector=EU@PERMANENT
echo CREATE A MASK 
r.mask --o vector=EU@PERMANENT  
echo CROP $i RASTER 
r.mapcalc "$i'_new' = $i'_old'"
r.mask -r 
done
```

I can see the problem is in the syntax used, as I get this ERROR message after `echo CROP $i RASTER`:

```
syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting '('
```

I tried also to use `r.mapcalc` with:

```
"$i'_new' = $i'_old'"
'$i'_new' = $i'_old''
"${i}'_new' = ${i}'_old'"
"$i'_new' = if(MASK,$i'_old')"
```

this last one following `r.mapcalc` manual page ( https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.mapcalc.html ), where it says

```
To mask raster map layer b by raster map layer a:
result = if(a,b)
```

and this: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Cropping_maps

But nothing works. Previous similar questions (e.g., [Loop using variable - r.mapcalc GRASS GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267702/loop-using-variable-r-mapcalc-grass-gis) ) didnt' help.
I am using GRASS 7.8.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 (from remote, I have Windows 10).

Comment: First, do you really have a GRASS vector named "EU@PERMANENT" ?? That's a strange name for a vector! In GRASS the word PERMANENT is reserved for the default mapset in a location. I would avoid naming GRASS maps like that.

Comment: Second, I think this can be easier than you have made it. Can we see the contents of `/myPath/myRasters.txt`??

Comment: Dear Micha, no, the vector name's just EU, I can also write `vector=EU`, correct? The file `myRasters` contains, in each row, the name of each raster as it is loaded in my current mapset (e.g., `raster_1`, `raster_2`, and so on), while the file itself would be `raster_1.tiff` (or `raster_1.img`), and so on. The file `myRasters.txt` has correct endings (I checked it with `cat -v`) and has a last blank row.

Comment: Be sure to quote the echo commands: `echo CROP $i RASTER` --> `echo "CROP $i RASTER"`.

Comment: Also: `r.mapcalc "$i'_new' = $i'_old'"` --> `r.mapcalc "${i}_new = ${i}_old"` (the curly braces are enough, no need for single quotes).

Comment: Hi markusN, is it recommended to quote the echo command? Why? And thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your answer in the comments, you have a text file with the raster names listed, row by row. So:

```
# Set region and mask once. No need to do this in the loop
echo "SET REGION" 
g.region vector=EU
echo "CREATE A MASK"
r.mask --o vector=EU

while read i; echo "CROP ${i}"; r.mapcalc "${i}_new = ${i}"; done < /myPath/myRasters.txt

r.mask -r
```

That should do it.